# Write a program entab that replaces strings of blanks by the minimum number of tabs and blanks to achieve the same spacing

Tags: beginner, c

My attempt at `Exercise 1-21` in the `The C Programming Language` book written by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie.

**Exercise Prompt**

Write a program entab that replaces strings of blanks by the minimum number of tabs and blanks to achieve the same spacing.

**sample.txt**

```
    apple   banana                  pear
```

**Expected Output with Test Text**

`\tapple\tbanana\t\t\tpear`

**Code**

````c
//Exercise 1-21. Write a program entab that replaces strings of blanks by the minimum
//number of tabs and blanks to achieve the same spacing. Use the same tab stops as for detab.
//When either a tab or a single blank would suffice to reach a tab stop, which should be given
//preference?

#include <stdio.h>

#define CHARMAX 1000    // max chars per line
#define LINEMAX 1000    // max total number of lines
#define TABSTOP 8


int main() {
    int ch = 0;
    size_t charCount = 0;   // running total of characters
    size_t lineCount = 1;   // running total of lines
    size_t space_count = 0; // running count of spaces

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        charCount++;
        if (ch == '\n') {
            lineCount++;
            charCount = 0;
        }
        if (lineCount > LINEMAX) {
            printf("\n!PROGRAM HALTED -MAX LINES REACHED- MAXIMUM NUMBER OF LINE ALLOWED IS %d!\n", LINEMAX);
            break;
        }
        if (ch == ' ') {
            while ((ch = getchar()) == ' ') {
                space_count++;
                if (space_count % TABSTOP == 0) {
                    putchar('\t');
                    space_count = 0;
                }
            }
            if (space_count != 0) {
                putchar('\t');
            }
        }
        if (charCount < CHARMAX) {
            putchar(ch);
        } else {
            while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
                ;
            }
            putchar(ch);
            lineCount++;
            charCount = 0;
        }
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you for putting your work out there, it's brave of you!
That is how we improve.

---

The motivation for CHARMAX / LINEMAX is unclear,
given that they are not part of the problem specification.
Gold star for giving each
[magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))
a manifest constant name.

The usual motivation for CHARMAX (or MAX_LINE_LENGTH, to distinguish
from total document length) would be to allow a `get_line()` function
to get away with static allocation instead of having to malloc().

The LINEMAX just kind of mystifies me.
I mean, what if `$ yes | entab` processes
an unbounded number of lines?
Is it somehow "correct" to bail after a while?
Or should the pipeline have looked like `$ yes | head -${LINEMAX} | entab`
if we wanted finite output?

---

```
    size_t charCount = 0;   // running total of characters
    size_t lineCount = 1;   // running total of lines
    size_t space_count = 0; // running count of spaces
```

Pick a coding standard.
There's lots to choose from, maybe GNU or Google.
And then stick with it.
In particular, avoid arbitrarily mixing camelCase with snake_case.

Kudos, the identifiers are wonderfully descriptive.

Consider deleting the `// comments`, as they don't really
tell us anything we didn't already know.

---

```
        } else {
            while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
                ;
            }
```

tiny style nit: The `;` semicolon on a line by itself is great,
it calls attention to "this is a no-op!". But it's maybe a bit
weird within `{` `}` braces. Use one or the other. This comes
back to: pick a style guide, write down which one, and adhere to it.
Which is a *lot* easier if you routinely use a linter or a
code reformatter which implements that guide.

Bigger item: We're discarding characters till end-of-line?
I don't find that in the original spec. Ok, fine, maybe,
write down the revised spec that you *are* implementing.
One can only report a code defect ("bug") with respect
to a spec. Missing specs cause endless misery.

Again, the usual motivation for such line truncation
would revolve around static allocation for a line buffer.
But your code makes no such allocation, so it just kind
of seems like gratuitous data deletion.

---

Here's a bigger critique.
Your loop features four `if` clauses, some with dependent clauses.
And there's quite a lot of mutation going on, the most
important being consuming input characters.

I don't find it especially easy to reason about
[invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_(mathematics)#Invariants_in_computer_science)
in this code.

Consider introducing a helper function that is responsible
for processing exactly one line of input text.
(For one thing, that makes writing unit tests *way* easier.)
Let's define a term.

def: We are at start-of-line when at start of input file,
and also right after we've seen a `\n` newline input character.

The outer loop invariant would be "we are at start-of-line each
time the while loop begins again", and helper would have
its own inner loop which is responsible for making the invariant true.
That is, it's responsible for consuming a full line and
returning control to the outer loop.

Here's an example document for a unit test.

```
sp16 = " " * 16
doc = f"{sp16}A{sp16}B"

expected_output = "\t\tA\t\t B"
```

I don't find it especially easy to reason about `space_count`
[OBOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error)
issues given the current structure.

---

Maybe the input is specified as having no TAB characters?

If so, we should signal an error upon encountering one.

If not, maybe reset `space_count` to zero?

---

> // When either a tab or a single blank would suffice to reach a tab stop, which should be given preference?

It seems the problem author was inviting an explicit response to this,
perhaps in the form of a comment.

---

Overall?

You seem to have adopted some novel requirements that don't appear
in the problem statement.

Running with those new requirements, the code appears to implement
them correctly.

There is an opportunity to structure the code into smaller chunks,
each having greater clarity for future maintainers who will
attend to bug fixes and feature enhancements.

Answer (score 3):

**Infinite loop**

Should a long and last line of input lack a final `'\n'`, the below is an infinite loop.

```
        while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
            ;
        }
```

Better to quit the loop if a `'\n'` or `EOF` detected.

**Unnecessary `CHARMAX, LINEMAX`**

Neither `LINEMAX` nor `CHARMAX` are needed to fulfill coding goal.

**Scant Tests**

Code deserves test cases where the space first occurs on line `offsets%8`  of  0, 1, 7 with lengths spaces runs lengths of 1 to 9.

Also test cases of lines starting with spaces of various lengths.

Consider also last lines that do not end with a `'\n'`.

Research `freopen()` for a way to automate testing of `stdin` via a file.

For DEBUG mode, consider any space that is ever printed is replaced with a `'.'` to ease visual testing.

I suspect a bug.

Comment: I noticed that Vim added `\n` at the end of every line after writing the buffer. I think I will edit my text files within my IDE to avoid this.

Comment: Happen to have any articles to share re: `Research freopen() for a way to automate testing of stdin via a file.`? Having a bit of trouble finding quality info on this.

Comment: @iamericfletcher [simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71316727/2410359).  Else you need a more specific request.